# Pandoc doesn't convert markdown headings into sections

Tags: conversion, pandoc, markdown

I'm trying out pandoc to convert markdown snippets in to tex, but for some reason it never converts headings. Here is the command I run, and the output I get:

```
$ pandoc -f markdown -t latex src.md
\# Heading

\#\# Subheading

Some \& ampersands.

``Here's a quote.''

\begin{itemize}
\tightlist
\item
  Here's a list.
\item
  One more item.
\end{itemize}

\textbf{Bold}

\emph{emph}
```

Instead of converting `#` into `\section`, it treats it as a character that needs escaping, similarly to ampersands. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The wrong escape is most likely because you are not starting the line with a `#`. That is, you input is

```
 # Heading (note space at beginning)
```

instead of

```
# Heading
```

Comment: The snippet I pasted is pandoc's output – my input file, of course, doesn't contain the escape characters, but regular heading indicators (`#`, `##`, etc). This is my problem – pandoc seems to add the escape characters during conversion.

Comment: Can you add what your input file is and what version of pandoc you are using.

Comment: @Elise: See updated answer